# Join statement on HQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

I have a tables called Category and CategorySet.

```
CREATE TABLE CATEGORY
(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    category_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(255),
    uuid VARCHAR(40)
);

CREATE TABLE CATEGORY_SET
(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    parent INT NOT NULL,
    child INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    FOREIGN KEY (parent) REFERENCES CATEGORY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (child) REFERENCES CATEGORY (id)
);
```

Category.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORY")
public class Category implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_NAME", nullable = false, length = 40)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "UUID", nullable = false, length = 40)
    private String uuid;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "CATEGORY_SET", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "CHILD")})
    private Collection<Category> subCategories = new LinkedHashSet<Category>();

    public Category(String name, String description, String uuid, Collection<Category> categorySets) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.uuid = uuid;
        this.categorySets = categorySets;
    }
}
```

I want to get all root categories which means they are not child category of any.

sql to get the result is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CATEGORY.id
FROM CATEGORY
  JOIN CATEGORY_SET 
    ON CATEGORY.id = CATEGORY_SET.parent
WHERE CATEGORY.id NOT IN (SELECT child
                          FROM CATEGORY_SET);
```

Can someone help me write HQL for this.

Comment: I guess your query wouldn't return root categories with no children

Comment: HQL works on entities, their fields and their associations. Not on tables and columns. So show us your entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HQL query is:

```
select c
from Category c
where c.id not in (select child from CategorySet)
```

Comment: I have one to many association with the CategorySet table. I have updated question with entity.

Comment: So "cc" will be the Category again which won't be having the child field in it. So it fails there.

Comment: Basically i need "Category" whose "id" is not there in "child" column of CategorySet.

Comment: If i am not wrong inner query should be from CategorySet. And no need of join.

Comment: But sub query is returning empty list always.

Comment: You asked for the HQL equivalent of that SQL query. If the SQL is wrong, so it is the HQL

Comment: Thanks for your help "select c from Category c where c.id not in (select child from CategorySet)"

Above query will work. Change you answer so that i can upvote.